# Página con asp.net y OWIN a veces redirige al Login aunque los datos sean correctos

Tags: c#, webforms, visual-studio-2019, owin

Estoy trabajando con un proyecto en asp.net webforms al que le he metido el sistema de Login mediante OWIN.
He instalado los Nugets Microsoft.Identity.Core, Microsoft.Identity.EntityFramework y Microsoft.Identity.Owin, he establecido la cadena de conexión y todo parecía que funciona correctamente ya que logaba cuando las credenciales eran correctas y cuando no, mostraba un mensaje diciendo que no eran correctas las credenciales.

El problema es que cuando el proyecto está recién publicado, todo el mundo puede entrar (si meten sus credenciales), pero si un usuario lleva más de un día sin logarse, se le redirecciona automáticamente a la página de Login (aunque los datos sean correctos).

En el web.config tengo lo siguiente:

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="account/Login" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

La página de Login tiene el siguiente código:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
    }

    protected void SignIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton1.Enabled = false;

        var user = SecurityInstance.Manager.Users.Where(u => u.Email == UserName.Text.Trim() || u.UserName == UserName.Text.Trim()).SingleOrDefault();

        if (user != null && SecurityInstance.Manager.FindById(user.Id) != null)
        {
            var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            var userIdentity = SecurityInstance.Manager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true, AllowRefresh = true }, userIdentity);

            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            UserName.Text = string.Empty;
            Password.Text = string.Empty;
            LblError.Text = "The user is not valid.";
            LinkButton1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    protected void SignOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        authenticationManager.SignOut();
        Response.Redirect("~/account/Login.aspx?forced=true");
    }
```

Además, depurando soy incapaz de reproducirlo (he intentado hacer un 'Attach to process' a un navegador de incógnito que no me deje logarme pero hay manera).
También he intentado depurar desde el navegador pero como solo hace una redirección no veo nada.

¿Por qué pasa esto?

Comment: a que te refieres con "pero si un usuario lleva más de un día sin logarse, se le redirecciona automáticamente a la página de Login (aunque los datos sean correctos)."

Comment: Me refiero a que si un usuario está más de un día sin hacer Login, cuando vuelve a intentar logarse es cuando le redirecciona a la página de Login. Es muy extraño porque los usuarios en ningún momento se deshabilitan. Además, cuando las credenciales del usuario no son válidas, muestra un mensaje. Pero esa redirección no sé qué la provoca ni cómo averiguarlo.

Comment: mmhhh si le agregas tiempo de expiracion al logeo ejemplo:  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="525600" slidingExpiration="true" />